# What Standards are covered in the Release Process?

Tags: standards, iso-9000, sox

I have recently been tasked with comparing our current release process with any existing compliance standards or other best practice standards to see what we are doing right, and what we might need to revisit.  My first thought is to examine ISO-9000 or SOX or CWE, but I really am not sure where to start. So my question for this community is this:

What Official Standards are there that govern, or speak to, a web-based software release process?

TIA!

Comment: Not SOX or ISO-9000.  According to [this Thoughtworks article](https://support.thoughtworks.com/entries/21615346-Increasing-SOX-Compliance-with-Go) a SOX audit only checks for a documented, repeatable process.  Similarly, ISO only expects the process to be documented.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the link to the Thoughtworks article.  The article implies that SOX does indeed care about the release process, so their are ostensibly specific sections within SOX that cover the release process.  I'd like to find those.

Answer (score 1):

I have used ISO/IEC 90003, which discusses how to implement ISO 9001 for Software Engineering as a guideline for areas that should be covered in a process.  There are a number of sections that discuss "release" depending on how the software is deployed.